# How to create a Kubernetes pod based off of an image pulling pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to restore a kubernetes pod that was deleted and believe my only option here is to replace the deleted pod with a new one. As you'll see with the kubectl get pods command, I'm trying to create a second pod of the name "hub- ". There is already one in the pod and you can see that it relies on other pods such as continuous-image-puller-2hhv4, hook-image-puller-dfcvg, and ngshare-85c7799db8-gw6hq. But you will also notice that there are duplicates of these pods, and I believe I need a second kubernetes pod of the name "hub- " in order to fix the issues of "Init: ". How can I create a new kubernetes pod based off of the other pods?

kubectl get pods command:

```
NAME                            READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
continuous-image-puller-2hhv4   1/1     Running       0          7h35m
continuous-image-puller-2qh7z   0/1     Init:0/2      0          7h35m
hook-image-awaiter-hjczt        1/1     Running       0          7h35m
hook-image-puller-7lcnx         0/1     Init:0/2      0          7h35m
hook-image-puller-dfcvg         1/1     Running       0          7h35m
hub-567bb6bc68-g5lcs            1/1     Running       0          7h35m
ngshare-586b877ff5-wg8sq        0/1     Terminating   0          85d
ngshare-85c7799db8-gw6hq        1/1     Running       0          34d
proxy-65d966d5b6-cz2rg          1/1     Running       0          7h35m
```

Comment: mmm.... did you try `kubectl logs continuous-image-puller-2qh7z -c <name of init container>` to figure what is wrong with the init? a pod usually doens't depend on another deployment's specific pod, so having 2 of those may not be the issue with the `hub-` one, but rather an issue with the fact that those pods are not meant to run with replicas > 1. 
The fact that they have suffix means they are controlled by a Deployment, so check on the deployments `kubectl get deployment` and eventually scale then back down to 1 `kubectl scale deployment continuous-image-puller --replicas=1`